# dhcp.ipAddress returns 0

Tags: android, wifimanager

When trying to get router IP address through WiFi manager not able to retrieve the same. Below is the code snippet.

```
WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
DhcpInfo dhcp = wifiMgr.getDhcpInfo();
System.out.println("ip add - " + dhcp.ipAddress + "gateway add -" + dhcp.gateway);
```

both IP add and gateway add returns 0 all the time.
I'm going wrong anywhere??? is there anything extra need to be done?

I've already gone through many related stack overflow questions but none have the answer for it.
Kindly go through the question, your kind speedy response would be of great help, let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Are you checking if Wifi network is available before getting dhcp info? When wifi is disabled dhcp info returns 0.

Comment: Hi Alvaro you are right, I was not checking before. Actually the problem was related to some timing issue. I am enabling network using wifiMgr.enableNetwrok() but after that I am not waiting for the operation to complete, before that only I was retrieving dhcp info. Now added delay and it is working.

Comment: Now I am getting IP address but while converting it to dotted format it is reverse IP I am getting, any idea how to take care of endian problem while converting integer IP to String IP??

Comment: See my answer if it is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

It returns null if RemoteException happens. Maybe you lack Internet permission in manifest file?

Comment: It is not returning null, it is returning 0

Answer (score 0):

You should check if any wifi network is available first, if not, `DhcpInfo.ipAdress` returns 0.

If you want to convert to dotted format, try this (if it is a valid IPv4 address):

```
try {
    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    int ipAddress = wm.getDhcpInfo().ipAddress;
    byte[] ipAddressbyte = BigInteger.valueOf(ipAddress).toByteArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < ipAddressbyte.length / 2; i++) {
        int temp = ipAddressbyte[i];
        ipAddressbyte[i] = ipAddressbyte[ipAddressbyte.length - i - 1];
        ipAddressbyte[ipAddressbyte.length - i - 1] = (byte) temp;
    }

    InetAddress myaddr = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddressbyte);
    String hostaddr = myaddr.getHostAddress(); // numeric representation (such as "127.0.0.1")
    Log.d("INET",hostaddr);
}
catch (Exception exc) {
    Log.d("Exception", exc.getMessage());
}
```